# How do get an NSView from a given location

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Given a screen position (e.g. during a drag operation) how would I find the view that's at that position in my application?

Converting the coordinates to window or source view coordinates is simple, but I can't find any routine to get a view from the given location. Is there any other solution than enumerating through all child views/windows recursively?

Please take this a bit further than just NSView's hitTest: message (which is a good answer). Is there a generic message to get the deepest view at a given position regardless of nested window hierarchies (without manually iterating all windows)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `NSView`'s `hitTest:` method:

> Returns the farthest descendant of the receiver in the view hierarchy
>   (including itself) that contains a specified point, or nil if that
>   point lies completely outside the receiver.

```
[[window contentView] hitTest:aPoint]
```

But the *aPoint* has to be in the superview's coordinate system:

> **Parameters**
>   *aPoint*
>   A point that is in the coordinate system of the
>   receiver’s superview, not of the receiver itself.

Comment: thanks for that. This solves my immediate problem, but what about child windows and their views? Is there nothing in NSWindow or at application level which can return this information without me manually iterating over all windows?

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to call `-[NSView hitTest:]` and it will return the view, if any, containing the point in question.  The receiving view should be your root view (such as the `NSWindow`'s `contentView`) and the point should be converted to that view's `superview`'s coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should rarely need it. The concept of "finding a view for an user interaction" is the responder chain. So, if a subview should respond to drag operation, simply add drag & drop capability to that view(s).

If you simply need the deepest hit on a view for that coordinate you can use `-hitTest` (`NSView`). Going up to your root view, you will find the parent views. If you have overlapping views, it becomes more complex. Please add that information to your question.

Comment: In my case this is only to solve another problem (determining a drag operation outside the originating view). But it is nonetheless an interesting task, even if not needed regularly.

Comment: Responder chain is the right concept to find a drag destination outside the originating view. Please get further information about the responder chain.
What do you mean with "subwindows"?

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad: Any window can have child windows, which are bound to it for user window drags. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/addChildWindow:ordered: (This is different from the concepts of “subviews” and “sublayers”; there is no hierarchy of windows.)

Comment: @Peter Hosey I know child windows. But as you said, they are no subwindows. And I cannot see any relation from  child windows to hit tests.